# How to debug Yarn application on Eclipse?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, remote-debugging, hadoop-yarn

I start with the MRAppMaster.java code.I want to debug into it to see the principle of a yarn application.

I import the whole compiled hadoop code in my Eclipse.

I run hadoop all in my local Linux.

```
4504 ResourceManager 
4066 DataNode 
4761 NodeManager 
5068 JobHistoryServer 
4357 SecondaryNameNode 
3833 NameNode 
5127 Jps
```

In hadoop-env.sh:

```
HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=9000"
```

And then I run：

```
bin/hadoop jar path/to/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar wordcount /wordcount /output
```

Then I set breakpoint in MRAppMaster.java and RunJar.java . Then start debug in Eclipse.

It only stop at :

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 342 in JobSubmitter)) 
JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(Job, Cluster) line: 342 
...
RunJar.main(String[]) line: 212
```

How can I debug into MRAppMaster.java?

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty late for you but I was also stuck in the same problem and figured out the solution, so posting it here.
First if you are looking for debugging MR job there is a post [here](https://pravinchavan.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/remote-debugging-of-hadoop-job-with-eclipse/) which explains it. 
and if you are looking for debugging TEZ job then you should add following to your tez-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>tez.am.launch.cmd-opts</name>
  <value>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7070</value>
</property>
```